# Uppercase data enter at application level

Tags: c#, winforms

One of our clients wants all entered data to be uppercased. I don't want to do it textbox by textbox, etc.

Are the any way to do it at application level?

Comment: what do you mean application level? you can always use `.ToUpper()`

Comment: There are many forms in the application. And grid controls, textboxes vs on the forms. I mean, if possible i want to implement it centerly, at one point. Maybe hooking keypress etc.

Comment: All data inputs must be uppercased. Not only specific ones. Maybe hooking message queue for keypress etc. can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** if you want to read UserInput in `UpperCase` you can use `ToUpper()` method.

Try This:

```
String str=textBox1.Text.ToUpper();
```

**Solution 2:**

if you want to Displayand read the UserInput in `UpperCase`, you can handle the `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox` as below:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.ToUpper();
        textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the KeyPress event once.

```
   private void txtBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.KeyChar >= 'a' && e.KeyChar <= 'z')
      e.KeyChar -= (char)32;
   }
```

32 is just the difference in ASCII values between lowercase and uppercase letters.

Comment: Implementing this for form would be better.

Comment: While this is a neat trick, it will fail when users enter letters outside of the Basic Latin alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the TextBox control, create a derived class that only works with uppercase, and use your derived class instead of the original TextBox.

This is a possible way to implement it:

```
using System;

namespace UpperCaseTextBox
{
    public class UpperCaseTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    {
        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectionStart = this.SelectionStart;
            var selectionLength = this.SelectionLength;
            this.Text = this.Text.ToUpper();
            this.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
            this.SelectionLength = selectionLength;
            base.OnTextChanged(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code has been tested, although it is just for demostration.

Note 1: I recommend to do this in a separated dll project, it will be easier to use (you have to <strike>compile</strike> build the control before placing it in the forms designer) and maintain. If you decide to create the dll, remember that you need to add a reference in the dll to System.Windows.Forms and also that you need a reference to your dll in your winforms application to use it.

Note 2: You may be interested in creating a variant of this by adding a new property to set the TextBox to normal, uppercase only or lowercase only. You may also want to create a mechanism to control this property for all the instances in your AppDomain (hint: that can be a static field). Why? Because you don't know what else will the client ask for next.